# How to find compatible versions of modules?

Tags: rust

Let a program need two crates: `foo` and `bar`, and `bar` have `foo` as a dependancy.

If you type:

```
foo = "*"
bar = "*"
```

in your `Cargo.toml`, you may have different versions of foo. The compiler sees `Foo` (version 1) as different from `Foo` (version 2). How to find the appropriate versions to make the build work?

My `Cargo.toml`:

```
piston_window = "*"
piston2d-opengl_graphics = "*"
pistoncore-sdl2_window = "*"
conrod = { version = "*", features = ["piston"] }
```

My program worked; then I wanted to do an update (because I need some newest things in the crates). I now have this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/view/run_conrod.rs:80:21
   |
80 |                     context,
   |                     ^^^^^^^ expected struct `conrod::backend::piston::draw::Context`, found struct `piston_window::Context`
   |
   = note: expected type `conrod::backend::piston::draw::Context`
              found type `piston_window::Context`
note: Perhaps two different versions of crate `graphics` are being used?
```

Comment: People usually see this for traits instead of concrete structs, but the solution is the same — use `cargo tree` to find the conflicting versions, then restrict the shared crate to a common version.